# Manually setting header for testing

Tags: java, servlets

I want to create a servlet class which receives two input parameters from a jsp let say login.jsp and thae servlet  "CommandQueueTestServlet" set those incomming parameter as a header parameter and then send the request and response parameter to another servlet "CheckForCommandServlet".

I need     to do this just to test my functionality because my "CheckForCommandServlet" will actually be invoked by some other application which has header     parameter.

But for my own testing I want to create a servlet  "CommandQueueTestServlet" for setting header.

Please check the below code what I am trying     to explain

```
javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CommandQueueTestServlet extends HttpServlet{

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response)
throws ServletException, IOException {


String hwId=request.getParameter("hardware_id");
String panelistId=request.getParameter("panelist_id")); 

// Setting input parameter as header parameter.Since request object dont have setHeader so setting in response
//object

response.setHeader("x-HwId",hwid);
response.setHeader("x-panelistId,panelistId);

// creating instance of CheckForCommandServlet and passing in doGet() method:

CheckForCommandServlet headerParam= new CheckForCommandServlet();

 headerParam.doGet(request,response);


 }
 }
```

---

```
 // Code for CheckForCommandServlet 

 public class CheckForCommandServlet extends HttpServlet {

 @Override
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {



    Enumeration enumeration = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();
    String headerName;
    String headerValue;
    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements())
    {
        headerName = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
        if (headerName == null)
        {
            headerName = "";
        }

        headerName = headerName.toLowerCase();
        headerValue = httpServletRequest.getHeader(headerName);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Header headerName " + headerName);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Header ParamaterValue " + headerValue);

    }

  }
```

How did my CheckForCommandServlet  get the headerParemeter set in  CommandQueueTestServlet as it is set in header parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The following lines:

```
// Setting input parameter as header parameter.Since request object dont have setHeader so setting in response
//object

response.setHeader("x-HwId",hwid);
response.setHeader("x-panelistId,panelistId);
```

adds two headers to the HTTP response that will be generated by the servlet container, and not to the HTTP request that is forwarded to the `CheckForCommandServlet` servlet.

Since your intention is to add a HTTP header to the original request so that a subsequent [`HttpServletRequest.getHeader()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) invocation would read the appropriate value, you may adopt the approach of using a [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html) that overrides the `getHeader` method, to return the values sent by the client. More details can be found in [this related StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter/2811841#2811841).

---

A better approach for the purpose of verifying the behavior of the `CheckForCommandServlet`, would be to use a HTTP debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Fiddler allows you to add [request headers automatically](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp) to a request issued by a client. All you need to do is to ensure that the client is configured to use Fiddler as the HTTP proxy.

Even if your intention is to write a light-weight unit test, it would be preferable to use a HTTP library like [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) in a client, instead of an approach that involves writing a request wrapper and a servlet with the additional overhead of requiring a test-specific WAR to built.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon Vineet Reynolds' excellent answer, Here's one way you can set HTTP headers using [java.net.HttpURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/CheckForCommandServlet");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("X-HwId", "Foo");
connection.setRequestProperty("X-panelistId", "Bar");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
connection.getInputStream().close(); //Must open stream to make request.
connection.disconnect();
```

You can wrap up something like this in your functional tests to assert on the response amongst other things.

---

**EDIT**

Using the  [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html):

1. Set the headers as request attributes.
2. Override `getHeader(String name)` and `getHeaderNames()` in your wrapper.
3. Forward to the target servlet using the wrapper in-place of the request.

Code (*note that I've removed imports for brevity*):

```
public class CommandQueueTestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        MyWrapper wrapper = new MyWrapper(request);
        request.setAttribute("X-HwId", "HardWare ID");
        request.setAttribute("X-PanelListId", "Panel List ID");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/CheckForCommandServlet").forward(
                wrapper, response);
    }

    private static class MyWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        public MyWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }

        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) {
            String header = super.getHeader(name);
            return header == null ? (String) super.getAttribute(name) : header;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
            List<String> headerNames = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
            headerNames.addAll(Collections.list(super.getAttributeNames()));
            return Collections.enumeration(headerNames);
        }
    }
}
```

You should now be able to use `request.getHeader(String name)` as usual:

```
public class CheckForCommandServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter()
                .format("Hardware ID = %s\n Panel List ID = %s",
                        request.getHeader("X-HwId"),
                        request.getHeader("X-PanelListId"));
    }
}
```

Even though this works, it's a rather brittle test and as Vineet has already mentioned, will require you to deploy a separate WAR. IMHO, using an HTTP library outside of servlet code in a test of some sort is still the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add headers to your HttpServletRequest, try this:

```
MutableHttpServletRequest mutableRequest = new MutableHttpServletRequest(request);
mutableRequest.putHeader("header", "headerValue");
```

where *request* is your HttpServletRequest object.