# How we can modify headers in request Object using Filter

Tags: java

I need to create a Filter and modify header values set in request Object. How we can modify headers in request Object using Filter?, there is no setHeader method available in request Object.

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP?

Comment: yes HttpServletRequest request Object

Comment: Use `HttpServletRequestWrapper` for this purposes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an HTTP Header to the request in a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper` to wrap the `HttpServletRequest` object passed by the server.

In the wrapper class you need to override `getHeader` method and return modified value of header.

You can refer to similar post over here [Modify request parameter with servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter)

Answer (score -1):

You can import Collectors using

> import java.util.stream.Collectors;

Add the method below into your class.

```
private Map<String, String> convertHeadersToLowerCase(Map<String, String> headers) {
    return headers
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().toLowerCase(), entry -> entry.getValue()));
}
```

Then before returning headers in the response, you should ensure they are converted before returning by adding the following into the Controller of your Response method:

> requestHeaders = convertRequestHeadersToLowerCase(requestHeaders);

Comment: OP asked about modifying headers in the *request*, not the *response*.