# Alter request header before controller method using @RequestHeader is called

Tags: spring

I have a few controllers that use the @RequestHeader annotation to get the logged in user. I cannot seem to find the correct way to alter the header before the method is called. 
I already tried to wrap the request and using an interceptor (in the prehandle method, if I'm not mistaken) and pass along the request,but it seems like the headers are not being queried. An exception is thrown by the servlet dispatcher that the username is missing in the header. 
Therefore I'm wondering whether someone knows how and when spring handles this annotation, so I can write the proper interceptor.

Don't have the code at hand, but if needed, I will post fragments later on. But the question is simple: how to inject a param into the request header when @RequestHeader is used on a controller method?

Kind regards,
Tom

First edit:
@Sotirios
I tried using the Filter, which works. But this is less convenient for me than the handlerinterceptor. Since I only need the filter for debugging. So again the better question: why isn't this not working with an interceptor?

```
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest) {

        @Override
        public Enumeration getHeaders(String name) {
            Enumeration headers = super.getHeaders(name);
            if( isUseFilter() && Constants.REMOTE_USER.equalsIgnoreCase(name) ){
                String user = super.getHeader(name);
                headers = enumeration(asList(isEmpty(user)? getDebuggingUserId() :user));
            }
            return headers;
        }
    };
    chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
}
```

Comment: Are you saying the request does not have the header, but you want to add it?

Comment: That is right. In my local development env, the right header has to be injected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding an HTTP Header to the request in a servlet filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis

Thanks for the link, now I have a solution I can use, but not the one I want though :)

Comment: Have you seen http://jpgmr.wordpress.com/2013/12/12/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-requests-with-spring-mvc/ ? He seems to adding a header using a interceptor without any problems

Comment: @geoand
It seems like he's altering the response and not the header.