# injecting headers in the url we will be redirecting to

Tags: java, jsp

i want to inject header in a url and redirect , i have tried the below link but it is not working . Please help how can i do this in java.

[Adding an HTTP Header to the request in a servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter)

```
  package com.bitplan.smartCRM.web;

 import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
 import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

 /**
 * 
 * @author wf
 * 
 */
public class RemoteAddrFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(req);
    String remote_addr = request.getRemoteAddr();
    requestWrapper.addHeader("remote_addr", remote_addr);
    chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response); // Goes to default servlet.
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter
// http://sandeepmore.com/blog/2010/06/12/modifying-http-headers-using-java/
// http://bijubnair.blogspot.de/2008/12/adding-header-information-to-existing.html
/**
 * allow adding additional header entries to a request
 * 
 * @author wf
 * 
 */
public class HeaderMapRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    /**
     * construct a wrapper for this request
     * 
     * @param request
     */
    public HeaderMapRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    private Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    /**
     * add a header with given name and value
     * 
     * @param name
     * @param value
     */
    public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
        headerMap.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        String headerValue = super.getHeader(name);
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            headerValue = headerMap.get(name);
        }
        return headerValue;
    }

    /**
     * get the Header names
     */
    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
        for (String name : headerMap.keySet()) {
            names.add(name);
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(names);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
        List<String> values = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
        if (headerMap.containsKey(name)) {
            values.add(headerMap.get(name));
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(values);
    }

}

}


  <!--  first filter adds remote addr header -->
  <filter>
  <filter-name>remoteAddrfilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.bitplan.smartCRM.web.RemoteAddrFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>remoteAddrfilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: can you add the code snippet that you tried ans whats problems/errors did you face?

Comment: Do I understand it right, that you want to get the **current request**, add/modify some headers, **respond with a redirect** to another page, and then have these headers in the **new request**? This is actually not possible (at least not without heavy coding, both server- and browser-side) - the browser sends a **new** request, so the modified headers are lost. Anyway, I can imagine some workarounds (e.g. using session).