# Read multiple properties file in one go using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest, api-versioning

I went through the link: [How to pass a Map<String, String> with application.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275736/how-to-pass-a-mapstring-string-with-application-properties) and other related links multiple times, but still its not working.

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring REST example. Link Question: [How to by default execute the latest version of endpoint in Spring Boot REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60144816/how-to-by-default-execute-the-latest-version-of-endpoint-in-spring-boot-rest/60145837#60145837).

I've created mapping something like this and simply read the mapping

```
get.customers={GET: '/app-data/customers', VERSION: 'v1'}
post.customers={POST: '/app-data/customers', VERSION: 'v1'}
get.customers.custId={GET: '/app-data/customers/{custId}', VERSION: 'v2'}
```

Code:

```
private String resolveLastVersion() {
   // read from configuration or something
    return "2";
}
```

Code:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource("classpath:restendpoint.properties")
public class PriorityProcessor {

    private final Map<String, String> priorityMap = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getPriority() {
        return priorityMap;
    }
}
```

Code:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest the following implementation:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="request")
public class ConfigurationProps {
    private List<Mapping> mapping;

    public List<Mapping> getMapping() {
        return mapping;
    }

    public void setMapping(List<Mapping> mapping) {
        this.mapping = mapping;
    }
}
```

Class Mapping will denote the information about the single mapping:

```
public class Mapping {
    private String method;
    private String url;
    private String version;

    public Mapping(String method, String url, String version) {
        this.method = method;
        this.url = url;
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Mapping() {
    }

    // getters setters here
}
```

On the Configuration or spring boot application class (the one with main method):
`@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigurationProps.class)`

In the properties file put:

```
request.mapping[0].method=get
request.mapping[0].url=/customers
request.mapping[0].version=1

request.mapping[1].method=post
request.mapping[1].url=/students
request.mapping[1].version=2
```

In Filter (I assume you followed my suggestion from the linked question):

```
    @Component
    @Order(1)
    public class LatestVersionFilter implements Filter {

       private List<Mapping> mappings;

       public LatestVersionFilter(ConfigurationProps props) {
          this.mappings = props.getMapping();
       }
    }
```

Comment: BTW, from what you're trying to achieve - consider using stuff like Spring Cloud Gateway project, Zuul 2 or even Nginx. If you'll have multiple microservices that have a common entry point (a gateway) - maybe you can do everything there....

Comment: I agree, Thanks for the great solution. This is best way to implement it if not using Microservices architecture. However I'm stuck with the small issue posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60146766/unable-to-read-properties-in-map-using-spring-boot