# Adding custom filter that add request headers in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I was using spring security to handle authentication via jwt that is passed in the request`s header:

```
public class JwtAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }

}
```

Now the JWT token is passed to my application in a cookie. I wrote a filter that takes the jwt from the cookie and adds it to the request`s header :

```
@Component
public class JwtCookieFilter implements Filter {
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;
        Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
        String jwt = this.getTokenFromCookie(cookies); // Inner method 
        if(jwt == null)
        {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            return;
        }
        HttpRequestWithHeaders requestWithHeaders = new HttpRequestWithHeaders (request);
        HttpRequestWithHeaders .addHeader("Authorization",jwt);
        chain.doFilter(requestWithHeaders, response);
    }
```

Now I'm not sure after what step my filter should run (configure method in springSecurity). I tried using the following but I keep getting 401 error (Unathorized) :

```
http.addFilterBefore(new JwtCookieFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to those of you who aren't familiar with Spring Security read the [following Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480102/how-spring-security-filter-chain-works).

The bottom line is that Spring Security is like a firewall that contains a chain of filters. Your request is going into the chain and trying to pass the filters there.

The filter that I created searches for a cookie and sets the cookie's value in the request's header. Since the class ServletRequest doesn't have a setter methods you need to wrap it with a [wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter).

After doing all this, the last thing that is left is adding the filter in the configure method:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //configuring strategy
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        http.addFilterBefore(new JwtCookieFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Please notice, all those calls in the configure don't actually run anything, they just set the "chain"/"filters" that spring will use for incoming requests.