I want to add the default header in all the request going to controller in spring boot
I need to add the headers based on the path to the incoming requests in spring boot, suppose if the  base path is /v1/users, request headers I need to add x-operation as "USER" and if the base path is /v1/pet I need to add x-operation as "PET", I need to add this before the request reaches the controller class in spring boot
I tried using Filter, HandlerInterceptor and WebMvcConfigurer but nothing seems like working
public class MyWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyCustomInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/v1/users/**", "/v1/pets/**"); 
    }
}

public class MyCustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    //unimplemented methods comes here. Define the following method so that it
    //will handle the request before it is passed to the controller.

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        request.setAttribute("x-operation", "USER");
        return true;
    }
}

I tried this but when tried to access in controller the headers is not added there x-operation.
Method 2:
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CustomHeaderFilter> customHeaderFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CustomHeaderFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CustomHeaderFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*"); // Set URL patterns to filter
        return registrationBean;
    }
}


@Component
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CustomHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        // Modify headers as needed
        HttpServletRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new CustomHeaderRequestWrapper(httpRequest, "x-operation", "USER");
        chain.doFilter(requestWrapper, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Cleanup logic
    }
}

class CustomHeaderRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private final String headerName;
    private final String headerValue;

    public CustomHeaderRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String headerName, String headerValue) {
        super(request);
        this.headerName = headerName;
        this.headerValue = headerValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
            return headerValue;
        }
        return super.getHeader(name);
    }
}

Method 3:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(1)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   
    StaticHeadersWriter pet_route = new StaticHeadersWriter("x-operation", "PET");
    StaticHeadersWriter user_route = new StaticHeadersWriter("x-operation", "USER");

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/v1/user/**").headers().addHeaderWriter(user_route);
        http.antMatcher("/v1/pet/**").headers().addHeaderWriter(pet_route);
    }
}

Any of the method above is not working

Method 1, you are addng an attribute not a header. Method 3, you are adding headers to the response not the request. Method 2 could work however there are more methods involved for getting headers and you would need to override all of them. You only dedcided to override 1.

@Divakar this should work, please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811769/adding-an-http-header-to-the-request-in-a-servlet-filter
